# How to check preprocessing time/speed in Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-preprocessing

I am training a neural network on Google Colab GPU. Therefore, I synchronized the input images (180k in total, 105k for training, 76k for validation) with my Google Drive. Then I mount the Google Drive and go from there.
I load a csv-file with image paths and labels in Google Colab and store it as pandas dataframe.
After that I use a list of image paths and labels.

I take this function to get my labels onehot-encoded because I need a special output shape `(7, 35)` per label, which cannot be done by the existing default functions:

```
#One Hot Encoding der Labels, Zielarray hat eine Shape von (7,35)
from numpy import argmax
# define input string

def my_onehot_encoded(label):
    # define universe of possible input values
    characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    # define a mapping of chars to integers
    char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(characters))
    int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(characters))
    # integer encode input data
    integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in label]
    # one hot encode
    onehot_encoded = list()
    for value in integer_encoded:
        character = [0 for _ in range(len(characters))]
        character[value] = 1
        onehot_encoded.append(character)

    return onehot_encoded
```

After that I use a customized `DataGenerator` to get the data in batches into my model. x_set is a list of image paths to my images and `y_set` are the onehot-encoded labels:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224)) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

And with this code I apply the `DataGenerator` to my data:

```
training_generator = DataGenerator(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(X_val, y_val, batch_size=32)
```

When I now train my model one epoch lasts 25-40 minutes which is very long.

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 16,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 16,
                    epochs = 10, workers=6, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

I now was wondering how to measure preprocessing time because I don't think it is due to the model size, because I already experimented with models with fewer parameters but the time for training did not reduce significantly... So, I am suspicious regarding the preprocessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To measure time in Colab, you can use [this](https://github.com/cpcloud/ipython-autotime) `autotime` package:

```
!pip install ipython-autotime

%load_ext autotime
```

Additionally for profiling, you can use `%time` as mentioned [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/01.07-Timing-and-Profiling.ipynb#scrollTo=8gmtVXoVd6vg).

**In general to ensure `generator` runs faster, suggest you to copy the data from `gdrive` to local host of that `colab`, otherwise it can get slower.**

If you are using `Tensorflow 2.0`, cause could be [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33024) bug.

Work arounds are:

- Call `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` at the start of the code
- Use `model.fit` rather than `model.fit_generator`. The former supports generators anyway.
- Downgrade to `TF 1.14`

Regardless of `Tensorflow` version, limit how much disk access you are doing, this that is often a bottleneck.

**Note that there does seem to be an [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12683) with generators being slow in TF
`1.13.2` and `2.0.1` (at least).**

Comment: Thank you very much! Training seems to be faster today. It only took 400 s per epoch which is a good increase :) I used model.fit() instead of model.fit_generator which seems to be a bit faster. I compared the two methods and model.fit() is 10 s faster at least. What I do not understand totally is how to copy the data from gdrive to local host in colab. How could I do this? And is this possible regarding the size of my data (aorund 2GB)?

Comment: @Tobitor If you still have the question on data copy, request you to create a separate question on that